# Does anyone know how to href varible profile of current user for a html link button, social engine

Tags: javascript, php, html, social-media

I am making a dashboard for user's home page for social engine, so areas are clear
For example - messages, settings etc

I want to have button saying "view profile"
but how can I href this link so it pulls in user's id?

I've tried
href the whole link upto /profile and adding php echo $engine4_users->user_id; etc

I also tried this in html clock, to make a button, but still it isn't working

```
<?php
$viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
?>

<a href="profile/<?php echo Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->user_id;?>;">View Profile</a>
```

I just want to make my own button link for all members that goes to that user's profile.

Comment: did you try like this way<a href="profile/<?php echo $viewer->user_id;?>;">View Profile</a>

Comment: i havent tried that @GauravSharma

Should this work within social engines html block

Comment: sorry but php dont work in .html file.

Comment: create a module widget

Answer (score 0):

php dont work in .html file so no php code will execute in html block. Please [create a module's widget](https://jadb.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/socialengine-4-create-a-widget/).

Answer (score 0):

To get URL of user's profile:

`$href = $viewer->getHref();`

To construct the link in template (view):

`echo $this->htmlLink($viewer->getHref(), "View Profile");`